# Can we call a big query stored procedure from Tableau?

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-desktop

I have a stored procedure routine in big query which I want to execute from Tableau. The idea is that the custom parameters from Tableau will be passed as input to the SP. But I don't see a way to use the SP from Tableau.

It doesn't show up in the list of available objects in the database.
I have tried using a custom SQL and use "CALL dataset.sp_name()" but it throws an error.

I have worked with stored procedures from other databases (like MySQL etc) in Tableau, but it's not working the same way for BQ.

Comment: what error it is throwing? use CALL project.dataset.sp_name()

Comment: Yes, I used the full name including project name : CALL `project_name.dataset_name.sp_name`('param')
It works fine when I run in BigQuery but throws an error in Tableau. You could try with any simple SP on your end as well. 
 
Error : An error occurred while communicating with the data source
Error Code:015CFBE6
The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got "(" at [:]

Comment: calling an SP in Tableau will introduce issues in daily refresh (extract), I would recommend using Views instead if possible